# Let $f$ be continuous, convex on $(−\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$, and has a local maximum at $0$. Prove that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function that is convex on $(−\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ and has a local maximum at $0$. Prove that the function $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

My answer: suppose $f$ is twice differentiable and $f'(x)$ exists at $x=0$.
Since at $x = 0$ there is a local maximum, then $f'(x) = 0$ at $x = 0$
And $f''(x)<0$ at that point.

Now if $f$ is convex on $(-\infty, 0]$, $f''(x)>0$ in that interval, and $f$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$,  so $f''(x)>0$ in that interval. So we can say $f''(x)>0$ in $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $f''(x)>0$ at $x=0$, which is contradictory to $f'(x)=0$ at $x =0$. So $f'(x)$ doesn't exist at $x=0$.

Am I correct? If it is wrong, please give me correct explanation.

Comment: I don't know math jax. But i think, my post is completely readable as there is no complicated math signs and symbol.

Comment: You can't talk about $f''$ since there is no assumption that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: Right said sir. But i couldn't find other way.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/876009)

Comment: what if $f$ is identically zero? excluding this, one can construct a function in accordance with the conditions, but differentiable at zero. (modify $x^2$)

Comment: f is given continuous, so i think it can't be piecewise.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assume  that there is a **strict** local maximum at $0$. Otherwise a counter-example is: $f(x)=|x|-1$ for $|x| \geq 1$ and $0$ for $|x| <1$.

So assume  that there is a strict local maximum at $0$.If $f$ is differentiable at $0$ then $f'(0)=0$ as you have observed. Now convexity on $[0,\infty)$ implies that $f'(0) \leq \frac {f(x)-f(0)} {x-0}$ for all $x >0$. Hence $f(x) \geq f(0)$ for all $x>0$. But $f$ has  local maximum at $0$ so we must have  a $\delta >0$ such that  $f(x)=f(0)$ for $0<x<\delta$.  But this contradicts the fact that there is  strict local maximum at $0$.